# Why bootstrap 3 tabs not working properly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have thi tab

<

```
li><a href="#neFrom" data-toggle="tab"  class="btn nav-link" >الأخبار</a></li>
                <li><a href="#GallaryForm9" data-toggle="tab"  class="btn nav-link" >الصور</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn nav-link" href="#">الفيديو</a></li>

 <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                        <div id="GallaryForm9" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input placeholder="" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                                <label for="first_name">الموضوع الرئيسي</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div id="neFrom" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input placeholder="" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                                <label for="first_name">الموضوع الرئيسي</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                                <label for="textarea1">النص</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col m2 s6">
                                <input placeholder="       /      / " id="first_name" type="text" class="datepicker validate">
                                <label for="first_name">التاريخ</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col m2 s6">
                                <input id="timepicker_ampm_dark" class="timepicker" type="time">
                                <label for="timepicker_ampm_dark">الوقت</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col m8 s12"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question lacks of details. What is not working properly ?

Then, your `<li>...</li>` items should be wrapped inside an `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` as [the official example from bootstrap v3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#nav-tabs)

Then, be carefull with css classes `in` and  `active`, because they controls the display behavior for your tabs.

Then, have a look on my implementation, I did **several changes**... Do not forget to include `Jquery`, as bootstrap **need it** for a lot of things.

```js
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a id="neFrom-tab" href="#neFrom" aria-controls="neFrom" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="True">الأخبار</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a id="GallaryForm9-tab" href="#GallaryForm9" aria-controls="GallaryForm9" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="False">الصور</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


     <div class="tab-content clearfix">
        <!-- FIRST TAB ACTIVE -->
        <div id="neFrom" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" aria-labelledby="neFrom-tab">
         <div class="input-field col s12">
           <input placeholder="" name="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
           <label for="first_name">الموضوع الرئيسي</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field col s12">
           <textarea name="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
           <label for="textarea1">النص</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field col m2 s6">
           <input placeholder="       /      / " name="first_name" type="text" class="datepicker validate">
           <label for="first_name">التاريخ</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field col m2 s6">
           <input name="timepicker_ampm_dark" class="timepicker" type="time">
           <label for="timepicker_ampm_dark">الوقت</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col m8 s12"></div>
       </div>

       <!-- SECOND TAB : NOT ACTIVE -->
       <div id="GallaryForm9" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" aria-labelledby="GallaryForm9-tab">
         <div class="input-field col s12">
           <input placeholder="" name="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
           <label for="first_name">الموضوع الرئيسي</label>
         </div>
       </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The demo snippet from StackOverflow does not run as expected, so i did the same in jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfue3tbd/1/).

Finally, you should consider **migrate to bootstrap v4** if possible.